# vm_area_struct - find MAP_ANONYMOUS mapping

Tags: linux-kernel, mmu

How I can detect that area represented by `vm_are_struct` was mapped as ANONYMOUS?
I assume that `vm_flags` field contains `VM_XXX` flags but doesn't contain `MAP_XX` flags. Besides that `vm_page_prot` field contains something unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

By checking `anon_vma` pointer (which should be set to non-NULL) and `vm_file` (which should be NULL, if mapping is related to a file):

```
if(vma->anon_vma != NULL && vma->vm_file == NULL) {
     // MAP_ANON
}
```

But `anon_vma` seem to be lazily allocated (not initialized immediately after `mmap()` is called).